How to find a 3-approximation algorithm for the minimum 3-CNF problem?
The minimum 3-CNF problem is the problem of finding the minimum number of literals $x_i$ of a formula $F$ to set true such that $F$ evaluates to true. In this problem all literals are positive. Now the question is how to find a 3-approximation algorithm for the minimum 3-CNF problem and prove it is a 3-approximation algorithm?
Hint: Use an algorithm similar to the approximate vertex cover algorithm.
